# Office365 REST API. Getting a 401 (Unauthorized) using ADAL

Tags: office365, adal, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to access the Office365 REST API using the ADAL library but get a 401 (Unauthorized), and can't figure out why. I have registered an application in our Azure AD, got an id, fetched a key for it and given it permissions to read the Windows Azure Active Directory.

I am able to acquire an OAuth token but it won't play with the Office365 API.

Here is one of my unsuccessful attempts:

```
  AuthenticationContext auth = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + myTenant);
  AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = auth.AcquireToken("http://Rest", new ClientCredential(myId, myKey));
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
  HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.GetAsync("https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events");
  // => Bam. 401. :(
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource ID you're passing to `AcquireToken` is invalid. That should be `"https://outlook.office365.com/"`. See if that helps. If not, try parsing your token and look for issues: https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/ValidatingYourToken.md

Comment: Thanks! The correct resourseid didnt help, But your token parser shows me that the logged in user tags (upn, unique_name, family_name, given_name) and - possibly worse - the permissions tag (scp:) tag are all missing. Clearly I'm missing somthing here. But what?

Comment: You might try using the common OAuth endpoint, "https://login.windows.net/common" in the constructor of the AuthenticationContext. Also, when you registered your app, did you specify application permissions or delegated permissions? What permissions did you give it altogether?

Comment: Jason, sorry for late reply and sorry to bother you with this tedious stuff. Please feel free to ignore me. The common endpoint complained about my app didnt exist. I tried set every single application and delegate permission. Still 401 :(.

Comment: Jason. I found this, buried in the http response: "The access token is acquired using an authentication method that is too weak to allow access for this application. Presented auth strength was 1, required is 2". I guess thats the path for me to follow. I'll keep this post updated.

Comment: Ok. From that error, it sounds like you're trying to do the client credential auth flow, which requires the auth strength of 2. That requires that you authenticate with a certificate rather than a client secret. Client credential auth flow is more for service apps that require access to all mailboxes in the organization. If you're just trying to access the logged-in user's mailbox, you should use the code grant flow.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on track now, thanks to your kind assistace and these two: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx
https://github.com/mattleib/o365api-as-apponly-webapp

Comment: @BaBu Correcr URL is now http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx